# dropdown2 to show the filtered result from table on selecting value from the dropdownlist1

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

in my DB table i have a column Type which has two categories Furniture and Electronics which is datasource of first dropdownlist. The other column is of name. I want my second dropdown to display all the names which are of type furniture and electronics names when i select electronics from first dropdown
i am using entityframework, here is the code

```
 protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> nameasset;
            
            if (DropDownList3.SelectedValue == "Furniture")
            {
                //Response.Write(DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
                nameasset = db.tbl_asset.Where(x => x.asset_type == "Furniture").Select(x => x.asset_name).ToList();
                DropDownList4.DataSource = nameasset;
                DropDownList4.DataBind();
            }
            else if(DropDownList3.SelectedValue == "Electronics")
            {
                //Response.Write(DropDownList3.SelectedValue);

                nameasset = db.tbl_asset.Where(x => x.asset_type == "Electronics").Select(x => x.asset_name).ToList();
                DropDownList4.DataSource = nameasset;
                DropDownList4.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {

            }
            
        }
```

also when i am selecting the furniture option from the dropdown it is by default selecting electronics over and over again and just displaying electronics items name from data base

Comment: so what's your question? it's not working?

Comment: it only working for Electronics, but not for furniture

Comment: since the code is the same for both you either have no "Furniture"-type values in your db.tbl_asset or the value of the DropDownList3 is not "Furniture".

Comment: There are two values of Furniture in Type in db.tbl_asset

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else - when and how do you bind your DropDownList3? can you share more of relevant code?

Comment: Yes Homungus you was the error was in the binding part of dropdownlist3 i haven't put it inside if(!ispostback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the `page_load` event. Please make sure to bind dropdownlist3 inside `IsPostBack`.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    DropDownList3.DataSource = [AddDatasource];
    DropDownList3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: still same but this time with an error 
Error CS1061 'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @brutospop Now answer is edited. I am sure this will work

Comment: @brutospop you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick button.

Comment: done, i am new so i don't knew that i have to click the tick

Comment: can you please also explain me why it didn't worked outside the notpostback ??

Comment: notpostback is the form property, it means that eigther the form is posted back to server or not. The problem in your code is, it binds the data when the page load. So when you select the dropdownlist item and form gets posted back, so it cannot came inside the ispostback block when the page reload again.